# sql performance vs php performance for string search

Tags: php, sql, performance

I was given a test for a new job, and I can't decide on which way to go, the question is as follows:

on a given database table (which I designed for another question):

```
message_id | INT PRIMARY AUTO_INCREMENT
user_id    | INT FOREIGN_KEY
from_id    | INT FOREIGN_KEY
message    | TEXT
```

let's say I want to search for a text in all the messages of a given user, would it be faster to do:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM messages m WHERE user_id='$id' AND message LIKE '%$string%';
```

or would it be faster to do:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM messages m WHERE user_id='$id';
```

and run on the result set I get, a `substr_count()`?

Or is there some faster, more efficent method to do this?

Comment: The best way to discover this is by trying it with some benchmark data, i think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always search on database side. Although a `LIKE '%word%'` causes always a full table scan, not every row has to get serialized, transferred to the client and deserialized again.

Also, if you can optimize the query to use a fulltext index or to match only the last part of a word (e.g. `LIKE 'word%'`) a full table scan wouldn't be necessary because it can be evaluated over an index (if it exists).

Comment: how would you suggest to optimize the query? I'm sorry, but I didn't understand fully if you could elaborate... if all the optimization is full text index or doing something more...

Comment: As I said: fixed prefix (``LIKE 'word%'``) can be evaluated over an index if it exists. So instead of querying ``SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = '%word%'`` you could query ``SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = 'word%'``, but I don't really know if that fits your needs. You are the only one who can decide that. Also, most database systems support a construct called fulltext index. For MySQL have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html, for PostGreSQL have a look at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch.html - with this you can search for unknown prefixes

Answer (score 0):

The first approach should be faster. If your objective is just to find the number of matching messages, it should be faster still to do:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM messages m WHERE user_id='$id' AND message LIKE '%$string%
```